.NET - Azure function not working scope log
Hello I have encountered a rather strange problem with the logs in Azure Functions for application insights. I'm not getting the logging of scope values working. I've tried different settings and still can't achieve this. In WebApi application it works without problems
Program.cs
.ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
{
    loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights("...");
})

Host:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "logLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 32,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:30:00"
      }
    },
    "eventHub": {
      "maxBatchSize": 64,
      "prefetchCount": 256,
      "batchCheckpointFrequency": 1
    }
  }
}

Log:
    using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["Scope"] = "Test" }))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Import check requested started");

        _logger.LogWarning("Test Warning");
    }

Result:

Thanks a lot

Not sure if related, but assuming Application Insights integration is enabled on the Functions resource itself, there is no need to call AddApplicationInsights in the code.

Also, fiddling with LoggerFilterRule mentioned here might help.

To add log below warning level scope you need to add this in you Program.cs file in .NET 8.
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
    {
        LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
            == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
        if (defaultRule is not null)
        {
            options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
        }
    });
})
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
})
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
    {
        console.IncludeScopes = true;
    });

    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
})

Edit:
This worked for me:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Isolatedfunc
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route ="test")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, Object> { ["Scope"] = "Test" }))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
                _logger.LogTrace("Test Tracing");
                _logger.LogWarning("Test Warning");

            }
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
        
    }
}

logLevel is not supported inside "applicationInsights" section in host.json.
host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
      "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
          "default": "Trace",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"      
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
          "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "excludedTypes": "Request"
          },
          "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}

OUTPUT:


Edit:


This answer does not reflect what is being asked, i.e. how to make logging scopes work with app insights.

@ZdeněkJelínek Updated my answer based on the scope.
